# Failed to find style 'coordinateLayoutStyle' in current theme

Tags: java, android-studio

This problem is showing up when i startup the basic Navigataion Activity template within Android Studio(3.1.2) and build tools(28)

**Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme**

I tried doing the following:

**1) adding the following line of code to the styles.xml file:**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
<item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
</style
```

**2) adding the following line of code in build.gradel(Module:app) file**

```
implemantation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

**3) tried running Clean Project->Build Project**

**4)tried running Clean Project->Invalidate Caches/Restart**

**5)Synced all my Gradle files**

Nothing seems to be working. Any help regarding this issue is much appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: In your Design view for your xml layout, is your theme set to "AppTheme.NoActionBar"? If changing that works, let me know and I'll post a more in-depth answer that covers how to get it to be that way by default. :)

Answer (score 0):

this is not contain directly **coordinatorLayoutStyle** in style.xml. You try this type of code for coordinate layout  i hope its work for you :-

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_155sdp"
    android:background="@color/colorThemeDark"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:stateListAnimator="@drawable/appbar_always_elevated"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:collapsedTitleGravity="left"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorThemeDark"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="center|bottom"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ExpandedAppBar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/categoryMainLogo"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_70sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_70sdp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/main_logo"
            app:layout_collapseMode="none" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#323642"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please give more discription what are you doing in your code

Comment: I just got into coding and Android app development, and this is my first project, a Navigation Drawer activity,  and this problem is consistent. @MaulikDadhaniya

Comment: you can direct use directly templet for navigation drawer in Android Studio. Why you create mannually?

Comment: I am using the default template for navigation drawer in Android Studio, and still I am having this problem. @MaulikDadhaniya

Comment: ooh delete your project or delete Activity and create again .

Comment: How do you recommend I proceed with the process ? @MaulikDadhaniya

Comment: I just ran into the same issue. Seeing that this question is only 3 days old right now, is it possible that this is a bug with the new version of Android Studio (3.1.2)? The solution @MaulikDadhaniya proposed, just deleting it and trying again, isn't a "real" fix unless this is a temporary issue (bug).